# Can someone please explain me the backtracking of this recursion, I don't know why but it is adding current vector to ans vector 2 times

Tags: c++, recursion, recursive-backtracking

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

void getAns(char s, vector<char> current, vector<vector<char>> &ans, int n, int i){
    if (i >= n) {
        ans.push_back(current);
        return;
    }
    
    if (s == 'M'){
    current.push_back('M');
    getAns('M', current, ans, n, i+1);
    getAns('F', current, ans, n, i+1);
    }
    
    
    if (s == 'F'){
    current.push_back('F');
    getAns('F', current, ans, n, i+1);
    getAns('M', current, ans, n, i+1);
    }
    
    
}

int main ()
{
    vector<vector<char>> ans;
    vector<char> current;
    int n;
    int index = 0;
    cin>>n;
    getAns('M', current, ans, n, index);
    for (int i = 0; i < ans.size(); i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < ans[0].size(); j++){
            cout<<ans[i][j]<<" ";
        }
        cout<<"\n";
    }
    


  return 0;
}
```

**input** -:
3

**output** -:
M M M
M M M
M M F
M M F
M F F
M F F
M F M
M F M

**Expected ouput** -:
M M M
M M F
M F F
M F M

SO there are two vectors first is an ans vector which is a 2D vector and second is a current vector.
But somehow current vector is being added to ans vector two times and I don't know why that is happening. I have just started learning recursion so if someone could help it would be really helpful.

Comment: please provide the actual problem or question that you are trying to solve here? also some test cases and your results.

Comment: @Jishnu [link](https://www.codingninjas.com/codestudio/guided-paths/data-structures-algorithms/content/118522/offering/1380914) , this is the question I am trying to solve. But above code is not a final solution, it's just a part of approach that I am trying to use.

Comment: Not the source of the issue, but interesting reading nonetheless: [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing `getAns` does if `i == n` is push `current` to `ans`, regardless of whether `s` is `'M'` or `'F'`.

So, when `i == n-1` and you make these two recursive calls:

```cpp
    getAns('M', current, ans, n, i+1);
    getAns('F', current, ans, n, i+1);
```

They will both cause `if (i >= n) { ans.push_back(current); return; }`, which means `current` will be pushed twice to `ans`.

To fix it, I recommend moving `current.push_back(s);` to the beginning of the function, before the first `if`, so it's always executed; and replacing `if (i >= n)` with `if (i > n)`.